# How to check if a record exists return true and if it doesn't return false C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm writing a get API endpoint that would return True if the record exists in DB and if the record doesn't exist endpoint should return false. At the moment my endpoint returns true regardless of the SQL stored procedure result.
I tried to do something like this
var result =await _offerRepository.
Then compare the results
if(result=='0') return false
return true
if If I follow this method I get an error "cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable "

Comment: If you expect to use the value returned by a method then that method has to actually return something. Obviously your `_offerRepository.CpgOfferStatus` method doesn't. You haven't bothered to show us that method so we can't tell you anything more about how to change it.

Comment: Do please read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need the stored procedure.

```
public async Task<bool> CpgOfferStatus(Guid tenantId, Guid advertOfferId)
{
    return _offerRepository.Offer.Any( x =>
        x.AdvertOfferID == advertOfferId && 
        x.TenantID == tenantId
        );
}
```

Comment: `Any` doesn't return a Task. :-)